# How to fix components of solution vector in fsolve?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

Say I have a function as follows:

```
function f = fun(a,b,c)
    f = a + b + c
end
```

Now I want to do find the solution as follows:

```
function f = find_a(b,c)
    f = fsolve(@fun, [0,b,c])
end
```

However, I’d like to keep `b` and `c` fixed, find only a solution for `a`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think it can be done by setting global variables, but I was wondering if there's a direct elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function with one input that calls `fun` with the fixed values of `b` and `c`:

```
function f = find_a(b,c)
  f = fsolve(@(a)fun(a,b,c), 0)
end
```